# Sam & Max 305: Eating Sal

Tags: sam-and-max-the-devils-playhouse

From all the hints (especially the one saying "I just don't know what Stinky sees in Sal..."), I've gathered that I need to get the giant Max to eat Sal to get further in the game. I've even managed to make him crave for cockroaches. But I haven't found anything to either make him crave for Sal specifically, or if a general cockroach is enough, to spot Sal. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spoiler answer:

> The problem was that I had not gained control of the legs yet. After showing my little cockroach friend to Sibyl, this problem was solved. After that, a simple stroll around with the giant Max brought me right in front of Sal, who was eaten on the spot.